# Why is the colour green associated with both growth and illness?

Tags: etymology, colors

Why is the colour [*green*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green) often associated with negativity? Green is paired with *jealousy*, *envy*, *vomit*, <strike>immaturity</strike>, etc. Yet it is the colour of growth and freshness. In other words, the natural association of the colour *green* is with something positive.

This is true down to its etymology, as the OED reports that the same Old German root **grô-** forms the basis for *green*, *grass*, and *growth*. And it says of *green* that  "the associations with verdure, freshness, newness, health, and vitality are widespread among the Germanic languages."

But, in English, (besides its use as *growth*) it is often symbolic of something negative, especially disease, which in some senses is the opposite of growth. Why is this? Is the origin of this association known?

[Etymonline suggests](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=green&allowed_in_frame=0) that green is the "*color of jealousy at least since Shakespeare (1596*)" (how/why exactly?). Could this be the source? If not, are there other explanations?

Note: yes, other colours can be associated with both positive and negative things, but this question asks about *green*.

Comment: I dispute your assertion: green is *sometimes* associated with negativity, but other times (and probably somewhere near as often) with positive things. Look at all the emphasis on "green" (i.e., ecology-friendly) practices and technologies. And for a billion Muslims, green [describes the state of the inhabitants of paradise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_in_Islam).

Comment: What makes _green_ particularly negative? Feeling _blue_ means feeling sad, _in the red_ means needing money, a _black heart_ means sinister, being _yellow_ means being cowardly... many different colors have both positive and negative nuances, depending on context.

Comment: @Robusto I have mentioned the _growth_ and _freshness_ aspect of it in my question. I find _that_ a natural association thanks to the abundance of chlorophyll and all the good things that come off it. However, there is no such natural explanation that I can think of for the others. IMO, the Islamic connection is [better explained here](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2009/06/islamic_greenwashing.html).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I've cited three examples in my question. Perhaps my wording is inadequate and I shouldn't have generalised it so.

Comment: @J.R. Red is _naturally_ associated with aggression. Similarly, blue has _natural_ qualities of serenity. In the _red_ etc., are artificial associations. With green, the _natural_ association is of _growth_. But the artificial associations all appear to be negative in their aspects. I have rephrased my question.

Comment: Doesn't seem all that unnatural to me - ever witnessed anyone getting seasick? Anyhow, you might find [this](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/1/messages/2195.html) interesting.

Comment: @J.R.  Quite - though Sappho is unlikely to have been known to medieval writers, there is ample evidence of their use of *grene* [here,1b](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED19378) for a sickly, livid complexion. In the famous Shakespeare quote, however, "green" is probably incidental; Iago is talking about a cat, and cat's eyes are typically in the green range, varying to yellow or blue.

Comment: @J.R. That link certainly is interesting and the answer to my question :) Thanks.

Comment: @StoneyB While "green-eyed monster" might refer to the cat, "green-eyed jealousy" is also used in _The Merchant of Venice_ which predates _Othello_.

Comment: @coleopterist   Oh, yes. But "jealous as a cat" is roughly the same vintage.

Comment: Please reopen this question @MetaEd. *Green* shares the etymology of *growth* and *grass* (and verdure, etc) yet it is also associated with illness, envy, etc. I think this is a legitimate and fascinating question and illustration of word usage.

Comment: related: [I'm a bit “green around the gills”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364916/im-a-bit-green-around-the-gills)

Comment: The color green is generally a good sign when seen on plants but a bad sign when seen on animals.

Comment: *Cupid's disease*, *Malady of France*, and *French gout*, Victorian euphemisms for syphilis and gonorrhoea, whose symptoms included thick green vaginal or penile discharge.  http://www.std-gov.org/stds/gonorrhea.htm and http://lakecharlesobgyn.com/Complete/458-Green-vaginal-discharge.aspx

Comment: I doubt that this is an English–language question.

Answer (score 10):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) acknowledges "the natural association of the colour green is with something positive," that is, with *growth*, and with "verdure, freshness, newness, health, and vitality", which association it says is "widespread among the Germanic languages", of which English is one. The word *green* is "borrowed from Germanic," says the OED. Of *green* in Germanic languages, the OED says that *green* is

> Cognate with Old Frisian grēne  , grēn   green, fresh, Middle Dutch groene  , groen  , grone  , grune   green, fresh, youthful, inexperienced, (of food) raw, untreated, also groene  , groen  , grone  , grune   (noun) green, greenness, greenery, verdure, grassy ground, vegetables, greens, green fabric (Dutch groen  ), Old Saxon grōni   green (Middle Low German grȫne   green, (as noun) green, greenness, greenery, verdure, grassy ground, fruit, vegetables, greens), Old High German gruoni  , gruone  , gruani  , cruone   green (as the colour of plants, some precious stones, the sea), fresh, healthy, (of food) raw, untreated, also gruonī   (noun) green, greenness, greenery, verdure, health, vigour (Middle High German grüene  , German grün  ), Old Icelandic grœnn   green (as the colour of verdure, etc.), fresh, hopeful, good, Old Swedish grön   green, fresh, new (Swedish grön  ), Old Danish grøn   green, fresh (Danish grøn)

Note *cognate* does not mean "borrowed", it means "Descended from the same original language; of the same linguistic family. Of words: Coming naturally from the same root, or representing the same original word." (OED). In the case of *green* and *grass* and *growth* they all descend from Old Germanic root *gra-  : grô- , which proto word *gra- is cognate with the Old Aryan *ghrā- to grow). So we're on solid grounds to say that there is an etymological association of *green* with *grass* and *growth*.

In addition, people take it as idiomatic that grass is green, even if "on the other side", where it is always said to be "greener" and in the axiom "as the grass is green" ([example](https://books.google.com/books?id=NyqQ4LRi6D0C&pg=PA195&dq=%22as+the+grass+is+green%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidla_q3pTRAhXH54MKHfm_DewQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22as%20the%20grass%20is%20green%22&f=false): "surely as the grass is green...")

The question, as  asked, using words from the actual OP:

> But, in English, (besides its use as growth) [green] is often symbolic of something negative. Why is this?

The OED acknowledges this "quite different and somewhat contrary development" and notes that it

> probably result[s] in large part ultimately from association with **ancient Greek χλωρός  green, pale** (see chloro- comb. form1) and with ancient and medieval medical traditions; compare classical Latin viridis  ‘green’ used of a ‘greenish’ complexion taken as a sign of illness or excess of bile.

Speaking of *bile*, note that a reflection of the Latin *viridis* is contained in the English word *[biliverdin](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/biliverdin)*, "a green bile pigment that is formed by catabolism of hemoglobin and converted to bilirubin in the liver." The *-verdin* in *biliverdin* comes from *viridis*.

We have the disease *cholera*, which [etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cholera&allowed_in_frame=0) says is ultimately from this same *khloros* (that is, *χλωρός*) "**pale green, greenish-yellow** (my emphasis)." The related Greek term *khole* means *bile*. And the "The excretions in this disease [cholera] were freqently described, especially, in early use, as containing large quantities of bile" (OED).

As does jaundice, which since the Middle Ages was also called **green jaundice**

> a disorder accompanied by greenish discoloration of the skin (cf. green sickness n. 1); specifically a form of jaundice in which there is accumulation of the green bile pigment biliverdin, usually as a result of biliary obstruction.

What about this *green sickness?* This was one of the most common diseases in the Middle Ages; it remained so until the 19th century when it was not diagnosed anymore and it has since become the forgotten disease. *Green sickness* was also called *chlorosis*, again pointing to the Greek influence.

Under *green disease* the OED says:

> A disease characterized by **greenish discoloration of the skin** =chlorosis

and gives references from 1547.

Under *chlorosis* the OED says:

> A disorder believed to occur almost exclusively in young, virginal women soon after puberty, characterized by **a greenish pallor of the skin**, cessation or irregularity of menstruation, and weakness, often accompanied by pica or other disturbance of appetite; an instance or case of this. Also called *green sickness.*

So yes, half the human race, that is, all young virgins could succomb to *green disease*, which was also equated with *love sickness*. [It’s Not Easy Being Green: 3 Cures for Green Sickness, “The Virgin’s Disease”](http://www.themarysue.com/green-sickness/) says that

> Green sickness was so common, many women had cures written in their home recipe books.

The same site, dependent on *Menstruation and the Female Body in Early Modern England* relates that one cure to green sickness was copulation (with one's husband); that is: virgins needed to get married and consummate the marriage. (See also *The Disease of Virgins: Green Sickness, Chlorosis, and the Problems of Puberty.*)

Note that even Shakespeare's Juliet was admonished by her father ('Capulet')

> To go with Paris to Saint Peter's Church
>   Or I will drag thee on a hurdle thither.
>   Out, you **green-sickness** carrion! out, you baggage!
>   You tallow-face!

([Act III, Scene 5](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=3&SC=5&IdPlay=32#231089))

Shakespeare also refers to the "green-sickness" in *Antony and Cleopatra* (III, 6), *Pericles* (IV, 6), and *Henry IV Part 2* (IV, 3).

The juxtaposition of green with pale, and one supposes illness, occurs in *MacBeth* [Act I, Scene 7](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=1&SC=7&IdPlay=13#159876):

> Was the hope drunk
>   Wherein you dress'd yourself? hath it slept since?
>   And wakes it now, to look so green and pale...

And Charles Dickens writes a letter in 1843:

> I am at this moment deaf in the ears, hoarse in the throat, red in the nose, [green in the gills](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364916/im-a-bit-green-around-the-gills),..and fractious in the temper from a most intolerable and oppressive cold.

which is the first recorded example in the OED of *green around (also about, at, in) the gills*. At the time of the letter, the use of *green* to mean *sickness* was well established.

As far as other "negative things," such as *jealousy, envy*, they flow from the same "development" (see above) as do *sickness* and *illness*:

> Of the complexion: having a pale, sickly, or bilious hue, indicative of fear, envy, ill humour, or sickness (also in *green and wan*, *green and pale*).

The use of *green-eyed jealousy* meant or implied being sick with it. If someone is 'green with envy' they are 'sick with envy'.

Comment: That made for a green and pleasant read!

Comment: Hi. I thought for a moment [you would award the 500 bounty to S.F.'s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70852/44619). Glad you didn't.  Personally, Id have chosen Shoe's answer. It has that needed reference you asked for.  Anyway, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Any given color can no doubt be associated with many things. I don't disagree that *a* natural association of the color green is with growth, but what makes you say *the" natural association? Yes, green is the color of leaves and moss and thus it seems natural to associate it with growth and abundance. But green is also the color of the puss from gangreene and people who are desperately ill sometimes have a green tinge, so green is equally naturally the color of sickness. In the United States our money has been green for a century or more so Americans often use the color green to represent money or wealth. (A common slogan of those who say their business is uninterested in the race of its customers or employees is, "We don't care about black or white, just green.") Green is commonly understood to mean permission or progress because a green traffic light means go. (Or maybe a green traffic light means "go" because the color green was associated with permission -- I can't say which came first.)

I suspect you could say the same about many colors. "Black" is often associated with the unknown or fear, presumably because we can't see in the dark. But it is also associated with finanacial solvency, because of the old practice of writing positive monetary amounts in black ink and negative amounts in red ink. Etc.

Comment: +1, I like your answer, but I have noticed that you forgot that green is the colour of  the skin of spatial aliens :)

Comment: Thanks! But the answer to my question lies within [this link] (http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/1/messages/2195.html) provided by J.R. All the other associations cited in your answer are, IMHO, "artificial". The choice of green in traffic lights is [explained here](http://observatory.designobserver.com/entry.html?entry=8627).

Comment: @coleopterist I agree that green as the color of money and traffic lights is "artificial" in the sense of man-made and probably aribtrary. But green as the color of pus and of sick people is certainly not. Again, you're picking one occurrence of the color green -- chlorophyll -- and declaring it THE natural thing that should be the inevitable only thing that should come to mind when we think of the color green, and then attaching one subjective meaning to that instance -- life and growth and vitality -- and insisting that that is THE meaning that should come to mind. ...

Comment: ... But why shouldn't I think of sickly green pus when I think of the color green? Or if I do think of leaves and grass, rather than think of growth and freshness, why shouldn't I think of "nuisance"? If I lived in a jungle, I might well think of growing things as bothers that have to be hacked away with a machete every time I want to walk anywhere. As a homeowner I often think of grass as something that has to be mowed constantly. Etc.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Where did you get the crazy idea that aliens are green? Everyone knows that aliens are gray. http://arcturi.com/GreyArchives.html

Comment: @Jay If you fall down the rabbit-hole that J.R. pointed out to us, you will see that it all comes together quite biliously. Seeing as to how this question has been closed by the hasty, I think that it's quite pointless to elaborate via a comment. I will grant to you though that my generalisation of green to be negative is a tad excessive. I have also noted this fact in a comment below the question.

Comment: Jay, I have got the idea seeing in [Area 51](http://sstatic.net/area51/img/header-moon-background.png). In the spaceship on the top, you can clearly see two green aliens :)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to be short. Healthy nature is (usually, in moderate climates) green. Green trees, green grass, all of this is considered fresh, healthy, vibrant. Brown or grey grass or trees remind us of late autumn or winter, when the nature largely "dies" and is reborn the next spring.

On the other hand, vomit is greenish (due to stomach excretions, bile, etc.). Human corpses are greenish in advanced stages of decomposition, due to interplay of stale (decomposing) blood and skin pigmentatation. For the same reasons, bruises turn greenish in time (fresh bruises are bluish). Very sick people may have greenish-yellowish hue due to presence of bile in the blood (liver failure). So yes, green, when relating to human appearance is a very bad thing.

Answer (score -1):

You may associate green with disease because surgeons often dress in green. They do so because bloodstains are less bright and scary on dark green or blue but both blood and fat (which is yellow) will show up in the textile.