# "You really take the biscuit!"

Tags: american-english, phrase-requests

Is there an American version of “You really take the biscuit!”? As in taking the last biscuit, i.e. it's incredible how selfish you are.

Comment: I'm afraid "you really take the biscuit" has about as much to do with "taking the last biscuit" as *incredible* has to do with *incredulous*, *there* with *their*, and *it's* with *its*. (Not to mention that including false etymologies in your question when all you really need to mention is the meaning is uncalled for.) But to reply to your P.S.: you post answers on this site by typing your answer in the "Your Answer" field followed by clicking on the "Post Your Answer" button.

Comment: I think you've confused matters by mentioning a biscuit in your explanation of the phrase "take the biscuit". Either that or you've misunderstood what "taking the biscuit means".

Comment: I'm not sure about the US, but equivalents to "taking the biscuit" in the UK that I know are: "taking the Mickey/Michael" and "taking the piss".

Comment: @Urbycoz - no it has nothing to do with taking the piss. One can say: _When it comes to taking the piss you really take the biscuit_

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70685/why-is-taking-a-biscuit-a-bad-thing-in-the-uk

Answer (score 2):

We do have the expression "you really take the cake" which could be used in the same context, but also means to be the best at something one does. E.g. "When it comes to comedy, he really takes the cake."

As for "take the biscuit", I've never heard it in the US.

Comment: I guess that comes down to the totally different meaning of biscuit.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain, something "takes the biscuit" if it is annoying and somewhat unexpected.  For instance, if you were waiting to get into a parking spot and someone else nipped in before you--that would "really take the biscuit."

Answer (score 0):

*Take the biscuit* or *cake* is excelling in something - positive or negative

So on its own it means nothing; after some act or some expression, it means you surpassed whatever was expected.

Here is my take

> When it comes to selfishness, you really take the biscuit/cake
>
> That was amazingly kind of you, you really take the biscuit

http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-tak3.htm has a rundown of etymology.

Answer (score 0):

[Take the cake](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_cake) is closest, though [take the biscuit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_biscuit) is used in a more uniformly negative manner.