# Where did "that really takes the biscuit/cake" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases

One says that something or someone (really) takes the biscuit when it or they have done something that you find extremely annoying or surprising:
For example: "she's opening your letters now? Oh, that really takes the biscuit!"

Comment: Have you done any research? There are plenty of explanations online. Google is your friend.

Comment: The meaning is quite clear https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that-really-takes-the-biscuit The usage is easily found - the Ngram begins in late 1800s and its popularity increases from 1960 onwards.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=takes+the+biscuit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctakes%20the%20biscuit%3B%2Cc0 But the origin of the expression is a bit more dificult to discover.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "taking a biscuit" a bad thing in the UK?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70685/why-is-taking-a-biscuit-a-bad-thing-in-the-uk) (however, I'd suggest looking past the accepted answer for a clearer understanding)

Answer (score 3):

"Take the cake" comes from this definition of "cake" found in the OED:

> *Cake* is often used figuratively in obvious allusion to its estimation (esp. by children) as a ‘good thing’, the dainty, delicacy, or ‘sweets’ of a repast. So ***cakes and ale, cake and cheese*** (Scotl.). ***to take the cake***, (†U.S. ***cakes***): to carry off the honours, rank first; often used ironically or as an expression of surprise. Cf. biscuit n. 1d.

The plural (now obsolete) "take the cakes" seems to predate the singular:

> Big Peach.—We were presented with a peach that grew on the farm of Capt. W. H. Turner, two miles from this place, which measured eleven inches in circumference, and weighing three quarters of a pound—beat this and take the cakes.
>   <sub>[Lexington Union](https://wordhistories.net/2017/11/30/take-the-cake-origin/) (Lexington, Mississippi), August 2nd, 1839</sub>

> Sherriff Moore takes the cake for the first wheat-harvesting in Ransom county.
>   <sub>*Lisbon (Dakota Territory) Star* July 25th, 1884</sub>

"Take the biscuit" comes a little later and is British:

> **Take the biscuit, to**, a variation of "take the cake"
>   <sub>[A Dictionary of Slang, Jargon & Cant Embracing English, American, and Anglo-Indian Slang, Pidgin English, Gypsies' Jargon and Other Irregular Phraseology](https://books.google.com/books?id=1NjWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA321), 1897</sub>

Comment: Thanks I had considered this (cake being a reward or award) but often in British English, "to take the biscuit/cake" is used to signify a negative outcome ( like (the straw that broke the camels back"). "Falling down the stairs was bad enough, but breaking my arm just takes the biscuit!"