# Where is Ogden Nash's "piece of cake"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, american-english

Prompted by the answers to my EL&U question, [Pinpointing its origins is not a “piece of cake”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431679/pinpointing-its-origins-is-not-a-piece-of-cake), I endeavoured to find out who was right. Did the idiom begin life in the US, in a poem written by Ogden Nash, or was it coined by the British RAF around 1938-1940?

For over two hours I tried to find the precise poem where Ogden Nash allegedly wrote the line

> Her picture's in the papers now,
>   And life's a piece of cake

It should be in his 1935 book, *The Primrose Path*, the OED and Phrase Finder claim it is the first time the idiom, *[a piece of cake](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UW2Gu7l2Nn0C&pg=PT242&lpg=PT242&dq=%22Ogden%20Nash%22%20%22piece%20of%20cake%22&source=bl&ots=vGeVtmdrOJ&sig=Z1q05YIASJ0y4dhPDZsj6QhUGIw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje9ISN0tfZAhVLORQKHTqfAGIQ6AEIdzAL#v=onepage&q=%22Ogden%20Nash%22%20%22piece%20of%20cake%22&f=false)*, appeared in print.

Well, you would think it would be easy as pie to unearth the doggerel in its entirety. We are, after all, on the Internet but you would be sorely mistaken. Try as I did, I did not find the line that preceded or followed the cited verse. I Googled, scoured the net, and followed promising leads all of which lead to nothing.

I tried via [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/primrosepath00nash) but no preview is available, I have since registered and I am currently on their waiting list

[image]

I used Google Books to search the exact phrase, but that too failed miserably. Here are the screenshots that show my failed attempts:

[image]

Entering "cake" in the search box pulls up two results, both of which are unrelated to the idiom "a piece of cake".

[image]

To give users an idea of Ogden's poetry, here is the only verse I found online that was published in *The Primrose Path*, it is about a pig.

> **Sigmund Freud**
>
> Who’s afreud of the big bad dream?
>   Things are never what they seem;
>   Daddy’s bowler, Auntie’s thimbles,
>   Actually are shocking symbols.
>   Still, I think, a pig’s a pig –
>   Ah, there, symbol-minded Sig!

Source: http://www.porkopolis.org/pig_poet/ogden-nash/

I searched for "pig" in the Google Books [search box](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KR01AAAAIAAJ&dq=Ogden%20Nash%E2%80%99s%20%22Primrose%20Path%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=pig), and a snippet appeared, although it says “Daddy's *Derby*, Auntie's thimbles.” Yet, I cannot find the verse or the title of the prose that *proves* Nash first used the idiom, *a piece of cake*, and not the RAF. It is baffling that Ogden's poem, used as supporting evidence by [innumerable sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Ogden%20Nash%22%20%22Primrose%20path%22%20%22piece%20of%20cake%22&num=20&ei=87mfWqS1CtHx5gLGhKzoCQ&start=0&sa=N&biw=1319&bih=620), is unfindable.

### Simple Question

- Has anyone got the book? Can anyone find the light verse where Nash wrote  "piece of cake"?

Comment: In case you're in the US, it's available on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/primrose-path-Ogden-Nash/dp/B00085A6RE).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that particular book on India's Amazon either. There's a compilation book worth about $25, though. I've sent myself a free sample. Let's see if it turns up anything. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I’m on the road this week but when I get back I’ll try to visit the local library. NYC’s public library system is very rich in its collection and I may be able to find a copy. Please remind me if you don’t hear back next week.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Off-topic because 'I asked a question about the origin of "a piece of cake", and I want to know in which poem I can find Ogden Nash's line.' is more than one question. The first question you ask 'Has anyone got the book? Can anyone find the light verse where Nash coined "piece of cake"?' is off-topic because it is a request for literary details; the etymology [Nash; 1935] is relevant here and given by yourself. I'd say that this concerns literature. As would you. Even if someone comes up with 'the light verse where Nash [used] "piece of cake" ', this will not prove first usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - this will nor prove first usage, but will prove that its  earliest available usage is from AmE. I think OP is asking in relation to their previous related question where they asked if “piece of cake was originally from AmE or BrE. Evidence of this is relevant and on topic.

Comment: @user5768790 Questions like 'Which poem?' and 'Can someone tell me exactly where in the book ............... is?' belong on LiteratureSE.

Comment: Mari-Lou, I have a copy of the 1935 American edition, but can't find the quote. The OED's attestations all come from a 1936 edition; for purposes of the "British or American" question it may be pertinent that there seem to have been significant changes made between the two. The OED has 12 attestations from the 1936 work, but I was only able to locate five of those in my book, and only one was on the page listed; the rest were randomly redistributed. More problematically, where the OED has "tank" (of beer) my version has "mug", so "piece of cake" might not have been Nash's own phrase.

Comment: @1006a Excellent news and the plot thickens! Why would one year make such a difference? I have seen several sources citing 1936, and a few citing 1935. Could it be everyone was simply copying the OED's citation? Could there be an American edition (*mug*) versus a British one (*tank*)? This could explain the Bowler (hat) vs Derby (hat) in the "Sigmund Freud" poem.

Comment: @1006a Will do. Inclement weather on the east coast has me stuck in TX at the moment, but will check with NYPL this weekend.

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain that there is an Atlantic divide between the editions; mine (1935) was published by Simon and Schuster in New York, but the OED's citation lists London as the place of publication. I haven't found anything that remotely resembles that line (or most of the OED's other quotations), but I will keep looking. I was mainly skimming the beginning and ends of sentences, but if it's actually a clause in the middle of a sentence I could have missed it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really nice of you to help clear up this mystery. It seems the 1936 edition holds the key, and if it was adapted to accommodate the British dialect, maybe "a piece of cake" was added by a British editor/publisher.

Comment: I typed out several nice comments with links, but unfortunately I commented on an answer that has since been deleted, and I'm not sure the OP ever saw them. Re why the difference between the 1935 and 1936 editions, the 1936 edition on abebooks and on Amazon mentions that that edition contains verse from multiple books: "contains a selection from two American volumes ; The Primrose Path & Happy Days ; also a few other verses written since the publication of those two volumes." It's possible the phrase of interest is in either Happy Days or the unnamed "few other verses".

Comment: @shoover "Happy Days" was published in 1933.  It is separately available in google books. https://books.google.com/books?id=BBoxAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22Happy+Days%27+%22OGDEN+NASH%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=piece+of+cake

Comment: Not an answer, but... I found a strikingly similar verse in Ogden Nash’s [_Many Long Years Ago_](https://books.google.com/books?id=LS5bAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Happy+Days%22+%22Ogden+Nash%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22jake%22) (1945) [snippet view]: “Her picture’s in the papers now, And everything is jake.” ...

Comment: Meanwhile, Hathi Trust reports that the “jake” version of the verse appear both in Nash’s [_Happy Days_](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=%22Her+picture%27s+in+the+papers+now%2C+and+everything+is+jake%22&id=uc1.b3711053&view=1up&seq=7) (1933), and in _Many Long Years Ago_, but the phrase “piece of cake” doesn’t appear in either. Nor does “piece of cake” show up in a Hathi search inside Nash’s _The Primrose Path_ (1935).

Comment: The earliest relevant Elephind results for “a piece of cake” are from Australian newspaper accounts involving RAF slang, including instances from [December 8, 1941](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/47172508?searchTerm=%22was+a+piece+of+cake%22), [May 1, 1942](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/78277391?searchTerm=%22is+a+piece+of+cake%22), and [October 23, 1942](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/128310279?searchTerm=%22is+a+piece+of+cake%22). I doubt that this usage is attributable to Nash’s poem. ...

Comment: Eric Partridge, _A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English_ fifth edition (1961) has this entry for the expression: “**piece of cake, a** ‘A thing that is easy to handle or an unmistakable opportunity,’ H[unt] & P[ringle, _Service Slang_ (1943)]: R.A.F.: since ca. 1938. ‘A cakewalk, a snip’ (H. & P.); or rather, perhaps, something as easy to take as a portion of cake. _It’s a Piece of Cake or R.A.F. Slang Made Easy_, by Squadron-Leader C.H. Ward-Jackson, 1943.” ...

Comment: You can read Ward-Jackson’s entry for “IT’S A PIECE OF CAKE” in his revised edition (1945) of _It’s a Piece of Cake_ [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZdMQDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22+The+Primrose+Path%22+%22piece+of+cake%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq38GdrfnZAhUE0GMKHbdfBBIQ6AEIVjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22piece%20of%20Cake%22&f=false). ...

Comment: And Christine Ammer, _The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms_, second edition (2013) has this: “**piece of cake** Something easily accomplished, as in _I had no trouble finding your house—a piece of cake_. This expression originated in the Royal Air Force in the late 1930s for an easy mission, and the precise reference is as mysterious as that of the simile EASY AS PIE. Possibly it evokes the accomplishment of swallowing a slice of sweet dessert.” ...

Comment: Ogden Nash was from Baltimore, Maryland. I can think of at least one instance where he amended a verse after initially publishing it. His original version of  “Reflections on Ice Breaking” (1931) reads “Candy/ Is dandy/ But liquor/ Is quicker.”  But in the late 1960s or early 1970s, he added two new lines: “Pot/ Is not.” So it is not beyond the prospect of belief that Nash at some point added or substituted “piece of cake” to his “everything is jake” poem. At any rate, I am skeptical of the claim that “life’s a piece of cake” appears anywhere in Nash’s poetry prior to World War II.

Comment: @SvenYargs welcome back. I look forward to reading an answer that even disputes the authorship of the idiom. The answer must lie in the 1936 edition.

Comment: @SvenYargs His poem with the "everything is jake" line is "I Have used it for Years", which appeared in the 24 June 1933 New Yorker.  https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1933/06/24/i-have-used-it-for-years

Comment: Libraries that have the 1936 edition of the book: https://www.worldcat.org/title/primrose-path/oclc/222071230  The closest to Northern Italy is 400km away in Germany.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're probably right, I'd expected them to be quite responsive on social media (keeping the dictionary popular), but as it turns out they only seem to be broadcasting their own content.

Comment: Just ordered [one of these on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B00168UCSK/ref=tmm_hrd_used_olp_sr?ie=UTF8&condition=used&qid=&sr=), might take a couple weeks to get here but at least it will settle this mistery. Seeing nobody could find this out easier I got kind of curious myself.

Comment: @JJJ wow, thanks. It's a 1936 copy, right? Please post the answer and I'll "pay" you back with Internet Rep! I promise ;>)

Comment: ILL is working on it, but that can also take a while. If a nearby university has it, probably by Monday, but otherwise...I can post what I found in the '35 version in the meantime, if you want.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m sorry, I haven’t had a chance. Work has been brutal. I’m going to Asia next week, hope it’ll calm down after that

Comment: @shoover your worldcat link doesn't directly lead to the libraries with the correct edition.  After you click on "just this edition", it tells you that Univ. of Saskatchewan and Univ. of Melbourne are the only two libraries in the world that have that edition.

Comment: @SvenYargs I added your find to my answer; please let me know if you'd prefer I take it out.

Comment: @1006a: I am glad that you considered it worth adding to your answer. Note that the same lines  (ending in "everything is jake") appear as a match in Nash's collection _Happy Days_ in 1933, according to the Hathi Trust website, three years before the edition of _The Primrose Path_ in which (according to the OED entry) "a piece of cake" first appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the book arrived today and I found the sentence, exactly on the page stated in 1006a's answer (page 172). I added some more links to photos at the end of my answer.

I also recommend reading the comments (both on the question and the answers), there are some interesting references to earlier versions of the poem in which *"And everything is jake"* took the place of *"And life's a piece of cake"*. It remains unclear whether the change was made by the author himself or a (British) editor.

The poem starting at 'Mrs. Sonia Katzenstein':

[image: cropped poem]

### Links to full-size photos

[First page of the full verse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZpN2.jpg)

[Second page of the full verse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11q1C.jpg)

[Freud poem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umUd8.jpg)

[Title page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOZA0.jpg)

[Publication information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keZQl.jpg)

Attribution: Nash, Ogden. The Primrose Path. London: Bodley Head, 1936.

Comment: This is the same poem that DavePhD notes was published in the June 24, 1933 issue of [_The New Yorker_](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1933/06/24/i-have-used-it-for-years), except that there the crucial couplet runs "Her picture’s in the papers now,/ And everything is jake." So the question is, why did Nash change from "And everything is jake" to "And life's a piece of cake"? Was he invoking an expression Britons were already familiar with? Or was he making up something new because he thought Britons might be less baffled by that expression than by his use of the US slang term _jake_?

Comment: @Sven: We actually don't know whether Ogden Nash changed it, or whether the British editors, completely baffled by the word *jake*, changed it.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually buying a hard copy,  the 300 bounty is yours. Could I ask you to copy the verse beginning with "Mrs Katzenstein", so visitors from Google etc.  searching the verse can find it here? As to "why" jake (US)  was changed to "cake" (UK) feel free to add a supposition, it will make your answer all the more complete. Thank you again!! So it's official, we have the physical proof that the first time the figurative meaning "piece of cake"  appeared in print was 1936.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, I have reformatted it so that all the trivia photos are links. Just one picture of the poem in the body now. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Ogden Nash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden_Nash) was a twentieth-century American poet, who authored over 500 poems. One of his books of poems was *The Primrose Path*,

The OED seems to be the source of the original citation of Nash's *The Primrose Path* as the earliest identified figurative use in print of ["piece of cake"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143547?redirectedFrom=piece%20of%20cake#eid30605987). The online entry for *piece*<sup>1</sup> includes, under Phrases, this entry and attestation:

> **piece of cake**  *n. colloq.* something easy or pleasant.
>   1936   O. N<sub><sup>ASH</sup></sub> *Primrose Path* 172  Her picture's in the papers now, And life's a piece of cake.

The citation details given are

> **Ogden Nash** · **The primrose path** · **1936**.
>   London

According to WorldCat (an online catalog of libraries around the world), there were at least two editions, one published in [1935 in New York by Simon & Schuster](http://www.worldcat.org/title/primrose-path/oclc/251702672?referer=br&ht=edition) and the other in [1936 in London](http://www.worldcat.org/title/primrose-path/oclc/222071230?referer=br&ht=edition). They seem to be rather different; the US edition is 354 pages of apparently all original works, while the UK edition is listed as a slim 218 pages and apparently contains ["A selection from 'The primrose path' & 'Happy days': also a few other verses ..."](http://www.worldcat.org/title/primrose-path/oclc/263927593?referer=br&ht=edition) (although the WorldCat entry for that version lists 354 pages).

These differences may explain why, of the twelve words and phrases that the OED attributes to *Primrose Path*, I was only able to locate six in the 1935 book, ***not including "piece of cake"***.<sup>2</sup> Of these, only one was on the page listed; the rest were randomly redistributed. On page 171, which is the cited page for the "piece of cake" quotation, there is a poem "The Strange Case of Professor Primrose" about an absentminded professor who accidentally becomes a Pullman Porter.

Interestingly, where the OED has "tank" (of beer) the version I have has "mug". This is similar to the "derby"/"bowler" difference raised in the original question. If Nash's British editors made a practice of suggesting (or unilaterally making) changes to the text, perhaps to make it more accessible to British readers, that could explain how an allegedly British phrase turned up in a book of poems by an American author.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>["piece, n." *OED Online*, Oxford University Press, January 2018, www.oed.com/view/Entry/143547. Definition P.15.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143547?redirectedFrom=piece%20of%20cake#eid30605987) Unfortunately, the OED is a subscription service; many people, including most UK residents, can access the OED online through their local or institutional library. Check with your librarian for more information.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Clicking on the link to "find more citations from *Primrose Path*" leads to quotations for the following twelve words and phrases; my findings or lack thereof are in parentheses:</sub>

1. <sub>Adamless, *adj*. 1936

   ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 218 Lonely Eve in an Adamless Eden. (Not located)</sub>
2. <sub>**beskirted in** be-, *prefix* 1936

   ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 165 And all the trim and not so trim ladies who have been be-trousered begin thank God once more to be be-skirted. (Not located)</sub>
3. <sub>beep, *v.* 1936

   ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 101 Beep the horn and howl the klaxon For Hebrew, Latin and Anglo-Saxon; Howling klaxon, beeping horn. (YES, “Beat That Light”, p. 343)</sub>
4. <sub>divot, *n* 1935

   ...1935 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 1936 105 The wretched golfer, divot-bound. (Not located)</sub>
5. <sub>hellgrammite, *n.* 1935

   ...1935 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 1936 122 This human hellgramite that I think we could all dispense with. (Not located)</sub>
6. <sub>over-inflate, *v.* 1936

   ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 14 Jonathan over-inflates his lungs. (YES, “Tell It to the Esquimos, or Tell It to the Esquimaux”, p. 60)</sub>
7. <sub>phooey, *int., adj.,* and *n.* 1936

   ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 185 And I'll say, ‘Phooie!’ or something of the sort. (Not located, but there is a poem entitled "Weather Clear, Track Fast, Horses Phooie!" on p. 303)</sub>
8. <sub>**piece of cake in** piece, *n.* 1936

   ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 172 Her picture's in the papers now, And life's a piece of cake. (Not located)</sub>
9. <sub>**setting-up exercise in** setting, *n.<sup>1</sup>* 1935

   ...1935 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 37 A few setting-up exercises. (YES, “There Is No Danger Line”, p. 37)</sub>
10. <sub>**symbol-minded in** symbol, *n.<sup>1</sup>* 1936

    ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 55 Still, I think, a pig's a pig—Ah, there, symbol-minded Sig! (YES, “Sigmund Freud”, p. 141)</sub>
11. <sub>tank, *n.<sup>8</sup>* 1936

    ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 46 What can a man..Ask..More than a pipe..And a modest tank of beer? (SORT OF, “Home, 99 44/100 % Sweet Home”, p. 117: *What can a man, can a family man Ask in the way of cheer More than a pipe, and a reading lamp, And a modest **mug** of beer?*)</sub>
12. <sub>**third baseman in** third *adj.* (and *adv.*) and *n.* 1936

    ...1936 O. Nash *Primrose Path* 38 Long have I wondered why a locomotive engineer should be so much nicer than an ambassador or a novelist or a banker or a third-baseman or a quartermaster or a lancer. (YES, “Ding Dong, Toot Toot, All Aboard!”, p. 108)</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>In fact, @Sven Yargs was able to track down a very similar line to the OED's "piece of cake" quotation, but without the phrase in question:</sub>

> <sub>Her picture's in the papers now, And everything is jake.</sub>
>   <sub>—</sub>[<sub>Ogden Nash, *Many Long Years Ago*, 1941 (snippet view)</sub>](https://books.google.com/books?id=LS5bAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Happy%20Days%22%20%22Ogden%20Nash%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22jake%22)

Comment: Don't forget the line in the Sigmund Freud poem, 1936, which I quoted: *Daddy’s Bowler, Auntie’s thimbles,*in the 1935 version it's "Daddy's Derby" So it seems some words were changed, which is rather odd for a poem. I wonder if the author left a preface or if the British editor wrote a foreword.

Comment: You're right, added!