# Why is the phrase "cake walk" informally used to describe an easy to achieve task, while its origin says a different story?

Tags: etymology, idioms, american-english, historical-change

From *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cakewalk)*:

> **cakewalk**
>   ˈkeɪkwɔːk/
>   noun
>   1. (informal)
>   an absurdly or surprisingly easy task.
>   "winning the league won't be a cakewalk for them"
>   2. historical
>   a dancing contest among black Americans in which a cake was awarded as a prize.

How did the phrase take a different meaning over time?

Comment: When I was a very young child in the early 1960s, my grandparents took me into the town nearest to their farm (which happened to be Weimar, Texas), to enjoy the annual town fair. One of the featured activities was a "cakewalk," which consisted of people slowly walking around a rectangle of numbered (chalk-marked) squares as music played. When the music stopped, the master of ceremonies would draw a number, and the person standing on the corresponding square would win a home-baked cake. Perhaps the idea that  a cakewalk is something easy arose from this alternative notion of a cakewalk.

Comment: This is the first time I have heard a cake walk described as a dancing contest. I have seen it used to mean a contest of bearing or deportment. Any effort that went into winning such a contest would have occurred in the past, so the contest itself would be, uh, a cake walk.

Comment: @SvenYargs I find the lottery style "cake walk" interesting. Having lived my life in the UK the only image I have of a Cake Walk is a fairground machine which tips the floor of a tunnel at strange angles as you walk through it throwing you off balance. We tend not to use "cakewalk" as a name for something easy but I have come across it and, thinking of the machine, I could never see why it had that meaning. Your lottery walk sounds like a likely source to me. Steve B's contest of bearing or deportment also sounds possible.

Comment: -1  The cited definition is *not* from [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cakewalk), nor from [**Wiktionary**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cakewalk). I thought it strange that Wikipedia didn't provide any background history.

Comment: When I was in elementary school in the 50s (in the Louisville KY area), a "cake walk" was a game somewhat akin to "musical chairs", where you walked around on a floor marked with numbers while music played.  When the music stopped you'd attempt to land on the nearest number.  Then a number would be drawn (as in a raffle) and the "winner" would be given some modest prize (such as a piece of cake, or perhaps a whole one).  There were no doubt many variations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The conflicting origin of a “piece of cake”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431679/the-conflicting-origin-of-a-piece-of-cake). *Black slaves would compete in ‘**cake walks**’ ... a piece of cake that was awarded as the prize to the best couple/team, came to be known among the blacks as something **very easy to obtain***.

Comment: I really don't see why anyone would think that a possible (but by no means definite) connection between cake walks and the phrase "a piece of cake" should suffice to render a question about "cake walk" a duplicate of a question about "piece of cake." And that is aside from the fact that the nineteenth-century sources that I consulted don't use the term "piece of cake" in connection with "cake walk." In the early (1870–1880) instances of "cake walk" that I examined, the prize for the winning walkers was consistently identified as an entire cake—not a piece of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the entry for *cakewalk* as a noun in J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994):

> **cakewalk** *n.* Orig, *Boxing.* an easy victory; (*hence*) an easy task. [First six cited instances:] **1877** D. Braham *Walking for Dat Cake* (pop. song title). **1897** Siler & Houseman *Fight of the Century* 46: It's a cake-walk for Jim...Fitz hasn't a chance. **1898–1900** Cullen *Chances* 53: It's a cake-walk fo' dat baby. **1910** *N.Y. Eve[ning] Jour[nal]* (Feb. 7) 10: Joe is the Marathon Kid and Samuel would be a cakewalk. **1916** in *OEDS I* 414: A fight that would not be a cakewalk. **1925** Fraser & Gibbons *Soldier & Sailor W[or]ds* 43 {ref. to WWI}: *Cake Walk, A:* an easy task.

Lighter is interested in the word as a slang term, not in its original, literal sense.

---

***Early newspaper notices of 'cake-walks'***

A search of the Elephind newspaper database finds instances of cake-walk in its original sense going back to 1870. An excellent description of an early cakewalk appears in "[A Negro Festival: The 'Cake Walk' at Mount Vernon](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030214/1870-07-20/ed-1/seq-8/#words=%22cake+walk%22),'" in the *New-York Tribune* (July 20, 1870), beginning with this somewhat iffy historical note:

> ...for Mount Vernon has its "Cake Walk," a festival most unique and most entertaining. This *fête* is, I believe, peculiar to the colored race, and although there nay exist no  written record of its history or of its origin it has been faithfully handed down among the traditions of the past from generation to generation, by sable grandmothers, until in our own day it has suddenly sprung up again in our little village.

and culminating in this description of the competition itself:

> Upon long tables were placed a number of cakes with other refreshments. The largest of the cakes were those destined as prizes to the successful walkers. The dark beauty who should be adjudged the best promenader was to receive the largest cake; the one who made the next best display would carry off the second cake in size—and so on. ...
>
> Loud clapping of hands, and even cheers, greeted them [three young women] as they started upon their expedition, which was to be three times around the room. Long and rapid were the strides of the tall maiden; short and breathless the quick stepping of the stout one; and easy and graceful the footfalls of the little one. Faster and faster they went, making no endeavor to keep step; flounces flew, and ribbons fluttered strangely—dark eyes flashed, and cheap jewelry glittered in the gas-light, as the aspiring three hastened around the hall, each one proudly expectant of winning the first cake. However, the trial was not for speed, but to see which one excelled in the fine art of walking; which one carried her head and shoulders erect; which one turned her toes out; and which one knew how to manage her arms and hands gracefully. All of these points were both gravely and comically discussed, and decided upon by the spectators.

A number of other announcements of cakewalks appear from 1874 onward. From an [untitled item](http://digitalnewspapers.libraries.psu.edu/Olive/APA/CivilWar/?skin=civilwar&BaseHref=HTJ/1874/03/18&EntityId=Ar00300#panel=search&search=0) in the *Huntingdon [Pennsylvania] Journal* (March 18, 1874):

> The festival and "**cake walk**" held in the Court House, last week, by the colored folks, was a success. They request us to return thanks to the public.

From an [untitled item](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth78404/m1/4/zoom/?q=%22cake-walk%22&resolution=4&lat=2017.5&lon=3604) in the *[Austin, Texas] Intelligencer-Echo* (March 1, 1875):

> A congregation at Utica, N. Y., proposes to hold a **cake-walk** and neck-tie festival to raise 200 to pay its retiring minister's salary. The services which cannot be compensated without a **cake-walk** and neck-tie festival must indeed be poorly esteemed.

From an [untitled item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038158/1877-06-14/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22cake-walk%22) in the *[Hillsboro, Ohio] Highland Weekly News* (June 14, 1877):

> The Colored Baptist Church will hold a Picnic on Thursday, June 21, and a Festival and **Cake-Walk** at night, in City Hall. Proceeds for the benefit of the church. Everybody invited to attend.

From an [advertisement](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=NYC18771222.2.30.2&txq=%22cake-walk%22) in the *New York [City] Clipper* December 22, 1877):

> GILMORE'S GARDEN, COMMENCING MONDAY EVENING, DEC . 17, GRAND NATIONAL COLORED JUBILEE AND BABY-SHOW, THE FIRST EVER HELD IN NEW YORK, CONTINUING ONE WEEK, and winding up with a regular "OLE VIRGINNY" **CAKE-WALK**. THE GREATEST NOVELTY OF TUE AGE! The exhibition of Colored Infants will be open every day after Monday, from 1 to 4 and from 7 lo 10 P. M. The whole in conjunction with THE GREAT LONDON CIRCUS[.]

Elsewhere in the same issue of this newspaper the following item appears under the headline "[City Summary](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=NYC18771222.2.47&txq=%22cake-walk%22)":

> The London Circus enters upon the tenth week of a remarkably prosperous season on Dec. 17. The extra attractions announced for this week are a colored baby-show, and, on Saturday night next, an old Virginia **cake-walk**. All the specialties of the circus company will be continued, and matinees are to be given dally until the close of the season, Dec. 31.

As for what exactly an "old Virginia cake-walk" entailed, this follow-up item in the "[City Summary](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=NYC18780105.2.38&txq=%22cake-walk%22)" section of the *New York Clipper* (January 5, 1878) indicates that it involved couples rather than single women (as in the Mount Vernon cakewalk of 1870), but that it remained a walking contest:

> A Virginny **cake-walk** at Gllmore's Garden on the night of Dec. 29 attracted a large attendance. Ten couples contended for the prizes, consisting of a gold watch, a cake containing a $20 gold piece, and a gold-mounted ebony cane. Frank Whittaker officiated as master of ceremonies, and received a cordial welcome as he entered the arena. In a vein of pleasantry he addressed each couple as they started upon their competitive walk, and later, in presenting some of the ladies with bouquets sent from the auditorium by admirers, his felicitous speeches elicited the applause of the audience. The best walkers were received with the usual marks of approbation, commingled with cheers and waving of handkerchiefs, and were recalled after the termination of their walk. The prizes were presented in the arena, Francis Griggs and Mme. Ray winning the watch, Miles Butler the gold-headed cane, and George Bay and Mrs. Hyatt the cake. Mrs. Bowser, one of the "cleaners" of the Garden, and her husband also participated in the walk, and were received with much enthusiasm by those who knew them. In the ring Mrs. Bowser was presented with a handsome bouquet, and Mr. Bowser with a suit of clothes, the gifts of members of the company. The usual circus performances were given.

The prizes went to the best (not fastest) walkers, so the activity in question again seems to have amounted to competitive promenading. It also seems not to have been an especially strenuous activity.

Likewise an [untitled item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038158/1880-01-15/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22cake-walk%22) in the *[Hillsboro, Ohio] Highland Weekly News* (January 15, 1880) indicates that a cake-walk had as much to do with poise and style as with physical exertion:

> The colored Cake-Walk held at Music Hall last Thursday evening was a very successful affair, and was well attended. The cake was carried off by Mr. Lud McFarland and wife, who were decided to be the most graceful walkers.

---

***'Cakewalk' as a sporting term***

When boxing slang picked up and redirected the term *cake-walk* by the late 1890s, it seems to have done so with the idea that the original, literal cake-walk  was not at all a difficult or physically punishing contest.

There is at least one scrap of evidence that horse racing may have picked up the term before boxing. From "[Extra: In a Walk: Joe Courtney Had an Easy Victory at Guttenburg Today](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030193/1891-02-18/ed-3/seq-1/#words=%22cake-walk%22+fight)," in the *[New York] Evening World* (February 18, 1891):

> Arizona [a racehorse] had a **cake-walk**. Mart Gibson [another racehorse] made a great bluff for nearly all the distance, when he quit very quickly and let Arizona walk in. Not Guilty [a third racehorse] was third.

But a few months later, in "[Display of Fistic Science](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=IJ18910522.1.3&txq=%22cake-walk%22+fight)," in the *Indianapolis [Indiana] Journal* (May 22, 1891), the term appears in the context of a prize fight:

> DISPLAY OF FISTIC SCIENCE:  Many Rounds Fought by Jackson and Corbett Without Advantage to Either: The Much Advertised "Mill" Declared a Draw in the Sixty-First by the Referee After It Hid Resolved Itself Into a "**Cake-Walk**."

Here the implication is that, after slugging each other for 61 rounds, both Jackson and Corbett were so tired that all they could do was hold onto each other and walk (or perhaps stagger) slowly around the ring.

---

***Conclusion***

Newspaper article discussions of cakewalks in the 1870s suggest that the claim that a cake-walk was originally a dancing contest may be ill founded. It is certainly possible that cakewalks evolved over time into dance contests, but in its earliest manifestations a cakewalk appears to have been (as it name says) a contest between walkers—and one that focused on the appeal of the walkers stride, balance, posture, and grace of movement.

Answer (score 0):

[Cakewalk](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cakewalk) as described by the online etymology dictionary is as follows:

> something easy," 1863, American English, from cake (n.) + walk (n.).
>
> Probably it is in some way a reference to the cake given as a prize for the fanciest steps in a procession in a Southern black custom (explained by Thornton, 1912, as, "A walking competition among negroes," in which the prize cake goes to "the couple who put on most style"), even though its figurative meaning is recorded before the literal one (1879).
>
> As a verb, from 1904. This may also be the source of the verbal phrase take the cake "win all" (1847).

[NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/12/23/256566647/the-extraordinary-story-of-why-a-cakewalk-wasnt-always-easy) has a fascinating article entitled "The Extraordinary Story Of Why A 'Cakewalk' Wasn't Always Easy"

The author writes:

> *By the 1870s*, a cakewalk was a popular feature of minstrel shows. The Oxford English Dictionary notes that *usage of the word "cakewalk" really began to take off during this decade. It was also when the word began being used as a way to describe an accomplishment that was easy or simple to obtain. This is not because winning a cakewalk competition was easy. Rather, it was because the dance steps were fluid and graceful. Hard work by the dancers gave the impression of great ease.*

A point I found interesting was the following:

> Here's how the dance worked: *Couples would stand in a square formation* with men on the inside perimeter *and then dance around the ballroom* "**as if in mimicry of the white man's attitudes and manners**," according to Richard Kislan. The steps included "a high-leg prance with a backward tilt of the head, shoulders and upper torso."
>
> **Plantation owners served as judges for these contests — and the slave owners might not have fully caught on that their slaves might just have been mocking them during these highly elaborate dances**.

More detailed information elaborating the thoughts above appears in [the Smithsonian's Stories from the National Museum of American History](http://americanhistory.si.edu/blog/who-takes-cake-history-cakewalk)

> Although the exact year and location are still undetermined, oral histories from enslaved people assert that the cakewalk began in the enslaved quarters of Southern plantations. The cakewalk was a grand-promenade type of dance, where couples would take turns performing. The couple with the best dancing skills would then "take the cake," an idiom that is still common today. But the cakewalk was more than a recreational dance; it also gave a chance for enslaved people to ridicule those who tyrannized them. The dancers would dress up in their finest clothes and parodied the mannerisms and dancing of the white Southern elite.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as a thoroughfare being cleared so that the carrier of a celebratory cake could pass through a room and arrive at a set destination without mishap!

Comment: You should have a look at the existing answers to see what is expected in terms of supporting evidence for an answer.